# Regex find string inside json string on html page

Tags: php, preg-match

I have some html code, which also includes a javascript tag and some json inside.

The json object looks like this:

```
var data =  {"service_notice":"111111-aa-bb-222222"}
```

I would like to extract the value for service_notice.  How can this be done with regex?

I am also concerned that it could be formatted slightly differently:

```
var data =  {"service_notice" : "111111-aa-bb-222222"}
```

or

```
var data = {
    "service_notice" : 
        "111111-aa-bb-222222" }
```

Comment: Can you use json_decode http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php ?

Comment: No unfortunately i have the code as a string.  It is included in an html string

Comment: `preg_match('#\{.*?\}#s', $string, $m);print_r(json_decode($m[0]));` Good day ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `json_decode`

```
 json_decode(substr($code, strpos($code, "{")-1, strpos($code, "}") - strpos($code, "{") + 2), true)
```

will yield an array that looks like

```
 array("service_notice"=>"111111-aa-bb-222222");
```

Thanks @HamZaDzCyberDeV

Comment: This will obviously fail since he's parsing it from an html code, something like this should do the job: `print_r(json_decode(substr($code, strpos($code, "{")-1, strpos($code, "}") - strpos($code, "{") + 2), true));`

Comment: Nope, edit your answer and I'll upvote since it's your idea :)